# WPF how to global layout

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am creating an WPF application. Approach: single window application, like web SPA app, with menu, header, footer and page content section. Then, in page, I should define at least page content, optional add some extra to menu, footer. Just like Master Pages in ASP.NET.

Is there any best practise, like Master Pages in ASP.NET, how to achieve this? I want to respect DRY and dont define Grid with menu, header etc in every page.

Thank you.

Comment: You would usually only have a single window with a fixed design and then you swap out components inside to change what you are looking at. Master pages don’t really make sense for WPF since you are not navigating away to somewhere else where you need to reconstruct the whole layout again.

Comment: MVVM will do... ContentControl/ItemsControl + data templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF, does not support the use of master pages. 
ASP.Net was originally made as an easier way to create web applications, like the way you create WPF application, only with a bigger variety of options, like the master page.

However, There are some best practices to achieve this in WPF, with the help of custom control.

for example: a custom control containing title abstract and content.

```
namespace MasterPages.Master
{
  public class Master : Control
  {
    static Master()
    {
      DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Master), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Master)));
    }

    public object Title
    {
      get { return (object)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
      set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(object), 
      typeof(Master), new UIPropertyMetadata());

    public object Abstract
    {
      get { return (object)GetValue(AbstractProperty); }
      set { SetValue(AbstractProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AbstractProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Abstract", typeof(object), 
      typeof(Master), new UIPropertyMetadata());

    public object Content
    {
      get { return (object)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(object), 
      typeof(Master), new UIPropertyMetadata());
  }
}
```

The full example is at:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23069/WPF-Master-Pages

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have followed your answer, combined with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140937/multiple-content-presenters-in-a-wpf-user-control

This solved my problem and seems to be a good solution how to keep WPF app DRY and well maintained

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to take a look at Prism https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism 
Prism supports regions.