# Multiple ItemsPresenters in a WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, itemspresenter

I'm doing something similar to [Multiple Content Presenters in a WPF User control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18140937/multiple-content-presenters-in-a-wpf-user-control).

I'm creating a visual widget for a conditional if statement, and I want there to be both true and false content.  Where it differs from the original post is that I want to be able to have multiple items in the true and false content.  Whereas I can bind ContentPresenter's Content property, ItemsPresenter has no similar thing to bind to.

Is there a way around this that I can build into the control (not just have the calling XAML wrap it in a Grid/StackPanel/etc.)?

```
    public class ConditionalBlock : Control
    {
        static ConditionalBlock ()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ConditionalBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ConditionalBlock)));
        }

        public ConditionalBlock ()
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0x45, 0x0F, 0x45));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LeftWidth", typeof(double), typeof(ConditionalBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(20.0));
        public double LeftWidth
        {
            get => (double) GetValue(LeftWidthProperty);
            set => SetValue(LeftWidthProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BottomHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BottomHeight", typeof(double), typeof(ConditionalBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(10.0));
        public double BottomHeight
        {
            get => (double) GetValue(BottomHeightProperty);
            set => SetValue(BottomHeightProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(ConditionalBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata("If"));
        public string Title
        {
            get => (string) GetValue(TitleProperty);
            set => SetValue(TitleProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HasSettingsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HasSettings", typeof(bool), typeof(ConditionalBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
        public bool HasSettings
        {
            get => (bool) GetValue(HasSettingsProperty);
            set => SetValue(HasSettingsProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TrueTitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TrueTitle", typeof(string), typeof(ConditionalBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata("True"));
        public string TrueTitle
        {
            get => (string) GetValue(TrueTitleProperty);
            set => SetValue(TrueTitleProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TrueContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TrueContent", typeof(object), typeof(ConditionalBlock), null);
        public object TrueContent
        {
            get => GetValue(TrueContentProperty);
            set => SetValue(TrueContentProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey HasTrueItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("HasTrueItems", typeof(bool), typeof(ConditionalBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
        public bool HasTrueItmes => TrueContent != null;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ElseHeightProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ElseHeight", typeof(double), typeof(ConditionalBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(10.0));
        public double ElseHeight
        {
            get => (double) GetValue(ElseHeightProperty);
            set => SetValue(ElseHeightProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FalseTitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FalseTitle", typeof(string), typeof(ConditionalBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata("False"));
        public string FalseTitle
        {
            get => (string) GetValue(FalseTitleProperty);
            set => SetValue(FalseTitleProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty FalseContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("FalseContent", typeof(object), typeof(ConditionalBlock), null);
        public object FalseContent
        {
            get => GetValue(FalseContentProperty);
            set => SetValue(FalseContentProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey HasFalseItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("HasFalseItems", typeof(bool), typeof(ConditionalBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
        public bool HasFalseItmes => FalseContent != null;
    }
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ConditionalBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ConditionalBlock}">
                <Grid Background="White"
                        Margin="0,1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <!--This is the top bar-->
                    <Border Grid.Row="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                            CornerRadius="4"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Margin="7,0,0,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                                Foreground="White" />
                            <Image 
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Source="{StaticResource SettingsIcon}"
                                Visibility="{TemplateBinding HasSettings, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                MaxWidth="10"
                                Margin="0,1,5,0"
                                Stretch="Uniform" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <!--This is the true block-->
                    <Grid
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding LeftWidth}"
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding HasTrueItems, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"
                        Margin="0,-3.5"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <TextBlock
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding TrueTitle}"
                            Foreground="White">
                            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"></RotateTransform>
                            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid 
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding HasTrueItems, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"
                        Margin="-1"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Border Margin="1,1,-1,1"
                                CornerRadius="2,0,0,2"
                                Background="White" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid 
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding HasTrueItems, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"
                        Margin="0,0,0,1">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding TrueContent}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <!--This is the else bar-->
                    <Border Grid.Row="2"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding ElseHeight}"
                            CornerRadius="4"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />

                    <!--This is the false block-->
                    <Grid 
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding LeftWidth}"
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding HasFalseItems, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"
                        Margin="0,-3.5"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Text="{TemplateBinding FalseTitle}"
                                        Foreground="White">
                            <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"></RotateTransform>
                            </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid 
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding HasFalseItems, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"
                        Margin="-1"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Border Margin="1,1,-1,1"
                                CornerRadius="2,0,0,2"
                                Background="White" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid 
                        Grid.Row="3"
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Visibility="{TemplateBinding HasFalseItems, Converter={StaticResource BooleanVisibilityConverter}}"
                        Margin="0,0,0,1">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding FalseContent}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <!--This is the bottom bar-->
                    <Border Grid.Row="4"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding BottomHeight}"
                            CornerRadius="4"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Use two ItemsControls, bound to the appropriate collection properties. Also, don't bind ContentPresenter.Content. Use `ContentSource`.

Comment: Are `TrueContent` and `FalseContent` supposed to be collections or single objects? If collections, I'd follow the example of ItemsControl.ItemsSource and declare them as non-generic `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Ideally TrueContent and FalseContent could either be single objects or collections.